# List of properties I can OlePropertyGet and OlePropertySet for Word.Application?

Tags: c++, ole, vcl

Working with C++ Builder 10 Seattle, and ComObj.hpp, plus digging up code snippets wherever I can find them, I have been able to make my Word doc look a lot like I want it to.

But it would really help if I had a link to the property *names* I can use when talking to each of:

```
    Variant FWordApp.OlePropertyGet("Documents").
              OleFunction("Add", StringToOleStr(t_template));

    Variant FWordDoc = FWordApp.OlePropertyGet("ActiveDocument");

    Variant FSelection = FWordApp.OlePropertyGet("Selection");
```

For example, I found a snippet that showed me how to create a table and write to its cells:

```
/* I want to get the current cursor position in the doc, but how? */
int headerlength = ??

/* The example I copied uses headerlength for both parameters
 * to "Range". I'm not sure that's what I want to do... I need
 * documentation to explain it. */
FTable = FWordDoc.OlePropertyGet("Tables").OleFunction("Add",
    FWordDoc.OleFunction("Range", headerlength, headerlength), 
    RowCount, ColCount);
```

I have been searching for examples, but sadly VBA and .NET code are not helping me to understand the VCL usage with OlePropertyGet and OlePropertySet.

I'm hoping that having a list of legitimate properties will help me stumble along. Help, please?

Comment: If you have the **Developer Tab** enabled in MSWord, you can use the **Visual Basic Object Browser** to view all classes and class members - lists all functions, properties, constants and events applicable to each class.

Comment: Thanks for that tip; I didn't know about the Dev Tab in Word. I can see I have hours of digging and following links to try to understand the MSDN docs (whimper).

Comment: Still at a loss: I cannot find documentation or tutorial that explains how to use the Visual Basic Object Browser to browse properties of objects such as Document header/footer, or the fill/background color of a cell in a table. I have, by-guess-and-by-golly, figured out how to get the current position in the document for placing the inserted table, and can change the font color of a cell in the table, which is nice... but having to guess is insane. Please, somebody, help me find documentation for using OleFunction, OleProcedure, OlePropertyGet and OlePropertySet to generate a Word document.